# osm2po is missing edges while importing to pgRouting

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2po

I am using osm2po for importing pbf file to PostgreSQL but when I find route using built-in algorithms I found that some of the edges are missing so route does not match with road.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Here is the link showing the missing edges [Missing Edges](http://1drv.ms/1hn9VM3)

Answer (score 2):

osm2po only takes roads into account, that are listed (and not commented out) in the configuration file. Did you take a look?

Comment: I haven't look there but routing engine of osm2po is giving excellent results with very good ground resolution but when i import sql file to postgresql and view all edges i realizes many of the nodes or edges are missed and route generated not lies on road, i don't know may be it is related with tilesize of osm2po, if you have any idea please tell me

Comment: You should probably contact the author of osm2po. I guess most effort goes into the osm2po router and eventually the SQL generator did not get updated for long time.

Comment: I have found that while creating sql file nodes which lies on intersections taken into account which leads to representing road in long straight lines.

Comment: Thank you all and especially C.Moeller, i was using x1,y1,x2,y2 for rendering thus missing the geometry in my route. Now i can generated smooth route by using geom_way column